# Got error 'is malformed or the scheme or host or path is missing during check out svn from Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, svn

I am using svn repository with my iPhone project,

My problem is when i am try to check out project it's give me error

**SVN : URL 'http://Presentation:81/svn/**

**'is malformed or the scheme or host or path is missing**

Host is reachable on above URL.

My Xcode version is 4.1

Please suggest me how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What URL do you use? It looks like the URL is incorrect. You should specify URL to repository (or a directory inside of a repo).

Answer (score 0):

svn does some things differently there. For example when using https://.. it sometimes complains that it couldn't verify a certificate while Safari and the rest of MacOS X perfectly can do it. The reason is that svn doesn't use the root cerficate storage of MacOS X and thus doesn't recognized manually added certificates but only uses its built in one I believe.

As you specify a hostname of "Presentation", it could very well be that svn does not autocomplete that name to the fully qualified domainname. So try with the full name instead.

Secondly the error string above starts the shown URL with a ' but doesn't end with one which somehow indicate you might have added a quote too much by mistake or it could simply be a copy&paste error.